# Array is too big for euclidean distance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, euclidean-distance

`my_array` is a sparse 78000 x 200 matrix of zeros and ones; many rows are only zeros. I am trying to calculate the euclidean distance. Further I use the multidimensional scaling to get the coordinates of every column (every column is a word in a vocabulary).

I get the error "array is too big" while calculating the euclidean distance. There are other similar questions, but I don't know how to apply it in this case. What I imagine is that if I reduce the precision of the "dist array" it will be less big, but I don't know how to do that. May also be working with sparse matrices or np.memmap, but the `my_array` is not a problem. The problem starts when it tries to keep all the distance values, so I need to integrate it during the `dist` array calculation. The `dist` array is a 78000 x 78000 matrix.

**So my question is, how do I integrate any of these techniques in the calculation of the euclidean distance?**

Or would it make sense to loop through `dist(x, y) = sqrt(dot(x, x) - 2 * dot(x, y) + dot(y, y))`? And adjust the data type somewhere in there?

```
from sklearn.manifold import MDS
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

my_array = np.array(Y[2:])
dist = euclidean_distances(my_array)
mds = MDS(n_components=2, dissimilarity="precomputed", random_state=1)
pos = mds.fit_transform(dist)
```